# Convert delphi's System.Copy to .net

Tags: vb.net, delphi

This is the Delphi code I'm trying to convert to .net:

```
   s1 := Copy ( s1 , 1,x - 1) + Copy(s1, x + 1,Length(s1));
```

I tried:

```
  s1 = s1.Substring(x - 1, 1) + s1.Substring(s1.Length, x + 1)
```

But I get error's when the index is out of range. in Delphi it works fine.

Added one line to convert..
       s2 := s2 + chr(3);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your parameters to [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) are reversed–the start index comes first just as in Delphi.

Delphi string indexing is 1-based. The .net string indexing is 0-based. You have the classic off-by-one error.

Finally, you cannot play so loose with the length parameter to `Substring`. In Delphi's `Copy` you can specify an arbitrarily large length value and you will get all the right-most characters. In `Substring` you must not ask for more characters than there are. If you do then `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is thrown.

You need this:

```
s1 = s1.Substring(0, x-1) + s1.Substring(x, s1.Length-x)
```

I'm assuming you have already ensured that `x` is in the range `0` to `s1.Length-1`.

---

As for your additional question,

```
s2 := s2 + chr(3);
```

translates to

```
s2 = s2 + Chr(3)
```

Comment: OK, but didn't my explanation above resolve all of that or do you still have problems?

Comment: I still have a problem its not the one I described in the question. I'll make a new question for that