# How do I convert a Delphi Copy operation to a .Net Substring operation?

Tags: .net, vb.net, delphi

I'm trying to convert code from Delphi to .Net. I'm stuck on one line:

```
//Delphi code
ss := Copy(ss, Length(ss), 1) + Copy(ss, 1,Length(ss) - 1); 

'vb.net code
ss = ss.Substring(0, ss.Length - 1) + ss.Substring(1, ss.Length - 1)
```

Delphi combines the two substrings, while .Net just concatenate them like a copy.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719873/convert-delphis-system-copy-to-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made the same mistake as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719873/convert-delphis-system-copy-to-net). You need

```
ss.Substring(ss.Length-1, 1) + ss.Substring(0, ss.Length-1)
```

All you need to do to convert this type of code is account for the 1-based vs 0-based indexing difference between Delphi strings and .net strings.

Comment: your actually right.. i don't know why it got changed last time... thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of subString in Delphi / Lazarus Code.

```
    function subString(input : String; first : Integer; last : Integer): String;
    begin
      Result := Copy(input, first + 1, (last - first));
    end;
```